# Xamarin forms breadcrumbs with horizontal stacklayout

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mobile-application, breadcrumbs

[image]

Tell me how to sell bread crumbs in xamarin forms app.
I found an article on google, but it does not show the implementation of how the label with breadcrumbs remains when switching to another page.
I also tried using nuget but it doesn't work for me.
I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried use this nuget package?https://github.com/IeuanWalker/Xamarin.Forms.Breadcrumb
As readme said

> For iOS add the following to AppDelegate.cs > FinishedLaunching

> BreadcrumbButtonRenderer.Init();
> you can see detail in the readme

Comment: Yes, I tried it, unfortunately it didn't work. Maybe there is a nuance when using it?

Comment: How it didn't work?

Comment: nothing happened after adding it to xaml

Comment: did you follow the readme and test the sample?

Comment: In the end, I came to the conclusion that I needed to do everything from zero, because I needed a wider functionality